# Cannot update .../tags folder in SVN Repository

Tags: plugin-development, svn

Could you please supply (I'm stupid) step by step process of what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

I uploaded my first plugin using tortoiseSVN. With some difficulty, I got the files into the /tags dir but I need to update/overwrite.

I really only want to present version 1.0. I added *.01, etc versions because was I was not able to overwrite. I need to update readme and the .php file, and ideally, to version 1.0.

Thus, okay (but I don't know how) to delete the tag files from server, or worst case, make version 1.03, etc.

Here it is: https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/responsive-mini-storage-calculator/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is an instruction I wrote for myself:

- Increment version nummber in plugin php file.
- Increment the "Stable tag" in readme.txt file to to the same number.
- Copy over all files from local plugin folder to the the D:\My_SVN_Folder\Plugin_Name\trunk
- Right click trunk folder and select **SVN Commit**
- Enter "Version X.X.X" and
- Save files to /**trunk** repository
- Write down revision number
- Right click trunk  folder and  select **TortoiseSVN > Branch/Tag**
- Change "To path" to /Plugin_Name/**tags/X.X.X**  The same version as the "stable" tag of the readme.txt
- In message field enter: "Tag X.X.X" or some other info
- Select option: **Specific version in repository**
- Make sure the revision number revision number matches the one from trunk commit.
- Save

As you can see it is two step process:

1. Copy updated files to trunk
2. Copy newest trunk version to tags/version number

Comment: Worked! I had to update version to 1.0x as I could not get SVN to overwrite. But at least it's working... Thanks!

Comment: John Pate: Welcome to WPSE. Please accept the answer from @abcfolio, if it solved your problem, to close the question.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I don't see an "accept the answer" button. Did you want me to use the "Answer Your Question" button? Thanks